# let msbuild generate target file names from source file names

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to figure out how to use MSBuild to create a set of dlls from a set of config files. That is, I have some config files

```
Policy.1.1.mylib.config
Policy.1.2.mylib.config
...
Policy.1.x.mylib.config
```

and in an msbuild target I'd like to call the AL (assembly linker) task with the list of these files, with the Outputfile parameter value (`Policy.1.i.mylib.dll` for each `i = 1, ..., x`) generated dynamically from the correesponding config file parameter. (All other parameters are explicitly known to me, so I can enter them directly).

I don't have much experience with MSBuild. I figured out how to run the AL task in a post build target for one file, and how to get the list of config file names into a list and do think I'd be able to loop over that list using batching, but I'm stuck when it comes to generate the target file name from the source file name.

(Note: This is msbuild 3.5, so seemingly there is no string manipulation as it seems to be in 4.0. Also installing additional libs from the net is not an option for me.)

Any suggestions? Maybe the approach as such is not well suited for MSBuild and I just don't see the proper way of doing this. The config files are generated programatically, maybe I should just in addition to these create a set of files to process, each containing the input and output names for al and have these read by MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd group the configs with an [ItemGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx) and that would give you access to [metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx)  for foreach-like looping and recreating a dll name, e.g. `<Task Input="%(Configs.FullName)" Output="%(Configs.RelativeDir)\%(Configs.Filename).dll" />`

Comment: Thank you, I could access the %(Config.Filename) within my <AL></> Task. The 'Fullname' did not work, however, I used "%(Configs.identity)" instead, an expression which I came across only by accident. I searched for quite a while for something like this, is there a reference somewhere which attributes (like ".Filename") are avaiable for this kind of listitem?

Comment: Yes, the metadata link in the answer is a list of well-known item metadata attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to create a list of assembly file names, create them in an item group by batching over the config file names:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ConfigFiles Include="Path\to\Policy.*.config" />
    <Assemblies Include="%(ConfigFiles.Filename).dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `Assemblies` item group will contain

```
Policy.1.1.mylib.dll
Policy.1.2.mylib.dll
...
Policy.1.x.mylib.dll
```